# VNC and Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, vnc

I'm trying to install a VNC server on a Lubuntu 14.04 install, but nothing works.

I have tried the [official documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop), as well as some [other](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/83) pages. I googled around and read some Stack Exchange's QA, nothing works.

Using Remmina, it will quickly fail unless I configure an SSH tunnel... after which it will just hang there and I have to `xkill` it.

Using `xtightvncviewer` on a remote PC, I simply get a connection refused. After following the official documentation :

#### Terminal 1

```
$ ssh -L 12345:localhost:5900 user@192.168.1.120
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Wed Oct  8 13:53:09 2014 from ibm-dev1
user@VTX-Server:~$ channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

#### Terminal 2

```
$ xvncviewer localhost:12345
xvncviewer: VNC server closed connection
[1]+  Exit 1                  xvncviewer localhost:12345
```

Did this happen to anyone? How can it be fixed?

Comment: I know that it has been a while and that nobody has given you an answer to your question but I can share that I've had much better experience with Vino than I have with tightvnc and that I use TurboVNC Viewer to connect. If you've resolved this then please let us know how. If you'd like to try Vino and Turbo then we can work our way through that - if you're still interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use VNC, but I've been using **[TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com)** for quite a while and I'm very satisfied with it.

TeamViewer is **multiplatform** (it can be installed on Linux, Windows and OS X) and it is **client and server at the same time**, I mean, in one single application: just install it on the machines you want and use it.

It works with a **static ID + dynamic password** scheme: each machine receives an ID and password. So, when you run TeamViewer, it will show you the static ID of your computer and its current password. If you want someone to access your computer, tell this person to run TeamViewer on his/her computer, then inform this person what's your ID and your current password. This person will then type your ID into his/her TeamViewer instance, hit "connect to partner", then type your password and hit OK. That's it.

If you download the TeamViewer **.deb** installation file, you can install it with `dpkg` by running this shell command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <path_to_package>
```

...where `<path_to_package>` is the full path to the downloaded TeamViewer DEB package. For instance, let's assume that your home folder is `/home/username` (a shortcut to it is the character `~`), that your downloads folder is `/home/username/Downloads` (shortcut: `~/Downloads`) and that you downloaded a file named `teamviewer_i386.deb` and saved it into your downloads folder. In such case, the downloaded package will be in `~/Downloads/teamviewer_i386.deb`, thus the installation command will be:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/teamviewer_i386.deb
```

Once the execution of the above command is finished, TeamViewer will be installed and ready to use.

Although the current version (11.0.57095) of the TeamViewer DEB package doesn't have any dependencies, it's not impossible that further versions have one or more dependencies - and in such scenario `dpkg` won't be able to install the DEB package, because `dpkg` doesn't solve dependencies. Thus, I recommend using [Gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gdebi/) instead of `dpkg`: Gdebi has a GUI (graphical user interface) and it automatically solves DEB package dependencies.

If you don't have Gdebi, I recommend installing it by running this shell command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi -y
```

If you installed Gdebi and now want to use it to install the TeamViewer DEB package (or any other DEB package), start Gdebi, select the **File** menu, hit **Open...**, select the DEB package, click **Open** and then hit the **Install Package** button. That's it: Gdebi will analyze this local **.deb** file for dependencies, automatically download the dependencies and install them.

Comment: This is what I ended up using in the end. However, the i386 package installs just fine with `dpkg`, no need for `gdebi`, I guess.

Comment: @YanickRochon The basic differences between `dpkg` and `gdebi` is that while `dpkg` is executed in the shell and doesn't solve package dependencies, `gdebi` can be executed in both the shell or GUI, and it solves dependencies. But the current TeamViewer DEB package is dependency-free, thus installing via `dpkg` or `gdebi` is up to the user. Glad to hear that TeamViewer sufficed to your needs. :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. My comment was merely to correct your answer, where some users may assume that `gdebi` is *required* while it isn't. A better answer would specify this :)

Comment: @YanickRochon I consider the installation of Gdebi an important step because I've already experienced issues with DEB packages having dependencies that could not be solved by `dpkg`, thus my conservative text/answer. I'm kinda worried about what might happen to users if a future version of TeamViewer has dependencies. 

But I must agree that the more options and explanations I provide, the better it is (more likely to be useful for a wider number of users), hence I've just edited my answer and added an explanation about how to install TeamViewer by using `dpkg`.

Comment: I found an alternative solution, although it only works if all machines have **Google Chrome** browser installed: Google Chrome has an extension named **Chrome Remote Desktop**. It's available at **https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp** and must be installed in all machines' Google Chrome browsers. It's multiplatform and works similarly to TeamViewer. After the installation, in order to access this extension it is necessary to access the URL **chrome://apps** and select it.